# standard error & variance of model predictions using merTools::predictInterval

Tags: r, linear-regression

I would like to estimate the standard error and variance of predictions from a linear mixed model. I'm using `merTools::predictInterval` to estimate prediction intervals because I want to include some of the uncertainty in the random effects (in addition to the uncertainty in the fixed effects). Is it acceptable to use the simulations from `merTools::predictInterval` to estimate the se and variance of predictions? If so, how should I calculate them? I can think of 2 ways:

To get variance corresponding to the prediction interval (i.e. including residual variance), I would first get the simulated predictions:

```
predictions <- merTools::predictInterval(...,  
                                         include.resid.var = TRUE, 
                                         returnSims = TRUE)
```

1. Then I could estimate variance using the normal approximation (calculate the distance between the fit and the upper/lower interval and then divide that by 1.96):

```
var1 <- ((predictions$upr - predictions$lwr)/2/1.96)^2
```

2. Or I could just take the variance of the simulated values:

```
var2 <- apply(X = attr(x = predictions, which = 'sim.results'), MARGIN = 1, FUN = var)
```

The SE would then be the square root of the variance. To get the SE and/or variance relating to the confidence interval, I could repeat this with `include.resid.var = FALSE` in the `merTools::predictInterval` call.

Is either of these methods acceptable? Is one preferable to the other?